# Does LeetCode ignore some semantic error in c++?

Tags: c++

I just finished a question on LeetCode, check out this line: `int visited[nums.size()] = {0};`, apparently it's wrong because you can't statically initialize an array without specifying its size, but somehow it worked on **LeetCode** and I even submitted it. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    result.clear();
    vector<int> v;
    v.clear();

    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    int visited[nums.size()] = {0};

    helper(result, v, visited, nums);     
    return result;
}

void helper(vector<vector<int>> &result, vector<int> &v, int visited[], vector<int>& nums) {
    if (v.size() == nums.size()) {
        result.push_back(v);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (visited[i] == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1] && visited[i - 1] == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        visited[i] = 1;
        v.push_back(nums[i]);
        helper(result, v, visited, nums);
        v.pop_back();
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Forget about the variable length arrays (which are not standard), and instead use `std::vector`.  The VLA's are more trouble than their worth, IMO. They can blow out the stack if the number of elements is large, you can't easily check for boundary conditions (with vector, you have the `at()`) function, and last, VLA's are not standard while `vector` is standard.

Comment: Can anyone also tell me why my question got down-voted?  It is my first question I've put on stackoverflow, I'm not sure whether I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[leetcode](https://leetcode.com/faq/) uses g++ 5.4.0 compiler for C++ compilation. It supports variable length array definitions. After ISO C99 specification, arrays with variable length declarations are allowed. [[Examples and Related Info]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: When I copy the code above to Xcode, it showed error. Did you mean my compiler does not support it but leetcode support it?

Comment: Xcode uses LLVM compiler. It is also supposed to support variable length array definitions. But it is enabled through an extension. Could you possibly check if it is disabled with Werror=vla? http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla

Comment: @GahitGungor, I'm not sure if I did exactly what you said, the error is **error: variable length array used [-Werror,-Wvla]** , and **error: variable-sized object may not be initialized**

Comment: I dive deep a little bit further, the result is both g++ and clang compilers are unable to initialize variable length arrays. The difference is, **clang** issues the error and **g++** doesn't. If you tried to initialize the elements something other than `0` like `int visited[nums.size()] = {3};`, elements in the array don't get initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the line `int visited[nums.size()] = {0};` is *not* wrong, although the it's not standard C++.

This is called a [variable length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (*VLA* for short). This compiler extension allows the length of an array be *not* a constant expression, just like in your example.